# Display only difference using diff utils

Tags: cmd, diff

I am using gnu diffutils to output the difference between two sql files using the following:

```
diff -e abc.sql abcd.sql >diff.sql
```

But the difference saved is also showing line number where it is found before the difference and a full stop after it.

I want to only display the difference and ignore the line number and the full stop.

Answer (score 0):

```
diff --line-format=%L file1 file2
```

From `man diff`:

```
   --line-format=LFMT
          format all input lines with LFMT

          LFMT (only) may contain:

   %L     contents of line
```

Comment: I also thought about this but I am not sure if it is the way it should be. For example, `diff --line-format=%L <(seq 10) <(seq 5 8)` does not show anything very representative.

Comment: and something like this ? `diff <(seq 10) <(seq 5 8) | grep '^<'`

Comment: Well the complete solution should be `diff <(seq 10) <(seq 5 13) | grep -E '^(<|>)'`.

Comment: and you can remove first characters : `diff <(seq 10) <(seq 5 11) | grep -v "^[0-9c0-9]" | sed 's/< //g' | sed 's/> //g'`

Comment: Yes, only that I am still wondering if there is any option in `diff` to do this, instead of cleaning its output.